# Constructor takes in its own type?

Tags: c++, constructor, segmentation-fault

I'm currently trying to work out a .cpp file for a project, but I'm getting a seg fault whenever I try to run it with the test file provided to met. I suspect I've found where the error occurs, but I can't for the life of me find a solution.

Basically, the class Product is initialized in the test file as seen below

```
Product * orderItem = new Product(*wonkaBar_retail);
```

Where wonkaBar_retail is a pointer to a Product object - so basically, the constructor for Product takes in an object of its own type... I'm not even sure that's supposed to work. As I said, this code, including the part that instantiates wonkaBar_retail was provided, so I tried compensating by making a Constructor like this

```
Product(Product) {
//Constructor in the header file
}
```

and even like this

```
Product(const Product&) {
//Other style
}
```

That just gave me a handful of compiler errors the compiler didn't even bother to explain...

Can someone clarify how this is supposed to work, and if this would even cause a segfault in the first place?

Comment: well the `Product(const Product&)` constructor is the copy constructor, the intent being to copy the passed in `Product` not to reference another.

Comment: use a debugger to find out where your code is segfaulting, or post more code. Debugging 1 line of code is impossible for us.

Comment: Can you please show how you have created `wonkaBar_retail` object and code inside constructor.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the members of the `Product` class and how the object `wonkaBar_retail` is generated?

Comment: Please provide the compiler errors, and also make sure that `wonkaBar_retail` is a valid pointer before you dereference it.

Answer (score 3):

The line you provided uses a *copy constructor* for the class `Product` which is perfectly legal. In fact, if you don't provide your own copy constructor for a class a compiler will generate one for you.

A copy constructor takes a reference to another object of the same type and initializes a new object to the same state as the other object. The copy constructor signature usually looks like this:

```
Product(const Product& other);
```

For simple classes the compiler generated copy constructor will work just fine, however for non-trivial classes, e.g. containing pointers to dynamically allocated objects you should implement your own.

Consider the following class:

```
class Buffer
{
public:
    Buffer(int dataSize) : m_dataSize(dataSize) { m_data = new char[m_dataSize]; }
    ~Buffer() { delete[] m_data; }

private:
    int m_dataSize;
    char* m_data;
};
```

The default copy constructor for this class will look like this:

```
Buffer::Buffer(const Buffer& other)
{
    m_dataSize = other.m_dataSize;
    m_data = other.m_data;

}
```

This is clearly not what you want. For one, if an object you copy gets deleted, the data your new object is pointing to will also get deleted. And then when you delete your new object you'll attempt to delete the same data twice, which is very bad.

What you really want to do then is to allocate new `m_data` for your new object and copy the data from the other object like this:

```
Buffer::Buffer(const Buffer& other)
{
    m_dataSize = other.m_dataSize;
    m_data = new char[m_dataSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_dataSize; ++i)
    {
        m_data[i] = other.m_data[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote anything, but I'll try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry it happened by mistake... you just edit the answer so that I can make up for downvote..